# Transition from Subversion to Git

Tags: git, svn

I need to migrate my SVN repositories to git. Each folder and file inside root must get it's own repository. I would love to script that process (existing repo is over 100mb in size and has a lot of different files and folders inside). Is there a way to query my svn to list all the subfolders and files. I can also move svn to the one git repo and than perform a git_split (it would be easier if we conider one authors file). Which sollution is better?

Comment: Did you look into `https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn`? To convert `svn` repo into `git` you can just do `git-svn clone ...`.

Comment: But it doesn't answer my question. I want to  perform svn2git on my svn but, each folder of my svn must get own repository. And to do so i need to be able to list my svn and then perform for loop which will make new repository.

Comment: you can do a filter when you do the clone to only pick up the folders you need for each new repo.  I [blogged](https://123code.co.uk/view/resources/migrating-a-subversion-repository-to-git) about it a while ago...

Comment: I want to automat tasks in this order: 
1. Create projects for each folder and file on my svn server.
2. Clone each svn forlder and file to its own git repository.
3. Push that to the gitlab. 
And no, there is nothing I'm looking for in the documentation.

Comment: `git-svn` provides for fine-tuning its understanding of the source repo layout, so I'd better check its docs as Arkadiusz suggested. Namely, look for `--tags`, `--branches` and `--ignore-paths` options.